# How can I Find Files On Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I find a specific file on an Ubuntu machine?

There's the `find` command but is there a graphical UI to find a file?

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for a GUI, but there is also other fast CLI ways, like:

- [updatedb](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/updatedb.8.html)
- [locate](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/locate.findutils.1.html)

The first command create a index, the second use the index to search. 
(maybe there is some GUI frontend to `locate`)

Comment: Thanks Johan--I'm not adverse to cli utitilies.  I just didn't know there were other utilities besides "find".

Answer (score 2):

Use **Places | Computer** (or **Places | Home** or any other location) and then use the 'search' button (its a looking-glass icon)

You'll soon go back to the command-line though ;)

Comment: Thanks--it's so obvious that I never even thought to look there. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few index based applications like [beagle](http://beagle-project.org/Main_Page) and [tracker](http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/) that offer GUI front-end. If you use [gnome-do](http://do.davebsd.com/) there is also a plugin there to use tracker as a backend. I am not sure about beagle, though.

Answer (score 0):

## Terminal (no gui)

You have two options:

## find

The `find` tool can be used as following:

```bsh
find -type f -name "data.txt" # search file that are named "data.txt"
find -type f -name "*.txt" # search file that end with ".txt" string
find -type d -name "*conf" # search file folder end with "conf" string
find -type f -name "*conf*" # search file that contains conf in their name
```

## locate

The locate tool work slightly different. In first instance you have to initialize a new DB that contains all the entry for your filesystem with the command `updatedb`. After some minutes that the index is generated, you can query the db using `locate file_name`

Main differences:

1. `find` does not need to index your file
2. `locate` need to create an index of the filesystem

## GUI

- Catfish
- gnome-search-tool (deprecated?)
- With Nautilus you can search by start typing the filename in the directory